# Arraylist value into string

Tags: java, arraylist

`for j=0` am getting arraylist like `[ rahul 25] ...for j=1` getting arraylist as `[rahu 25 arjun 30].`
for j=2`getting arraylist as`[rahul 25 arjun 30 karthik 24]`.

I am converting these array lists to strings.

`for j= 2`

am getting result as name :: `[rahul rahul rahul ]`
                     age  :: `[25 25 25]`

result has to be like name ::`[rahul arjun karthik]`
                      age ::`[25 30 24].`

```
private void data(ArrayList<person> list)
{

  ArrayList<String> nameValue = new ArrayList<String>();        
  ArrayList<String>  ageValue = new ArrayList<String>();        

  String name,age=null;

  int j=0;              
  String data=null; 
  String[] parts = null;



for ( j = 0; j <= list.size(); j++) 
{                   

  data=list.toString(); 
  System.out.println("arraylist :::::"+data);
  parts = da.split(" ");
  name = parts[0]; 
  age = parts[1]; 
}

           nameVlaue.add(name);
       ageValue.add(age);

System.out.println("name::"+ nameVlaue.add(name));//                
System.out.println("age ::"+ ageValue.add(age));
```

Comment: Please intend your code. Please.

Comment: code is not clear , post your input array , then the desired output you want

Comment: What is your question? It won't compile about the typo. Even if you corrct the typo in the line `da.split(" ")` it won't do what I think you want to accomplish, but I don't like to guess

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the below changes.

```
for ( j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) // j<list.size(), equals will give an IOOBE
{                   
  data=list.get(j).toString(); // Get the next object always, not the list as a whole
  // I hope the toString() method of your Person class gives the output as space delimited
  System.out.println("arraylist :::::"+data);
  parts = data.split(" "); // Split the data, not da
  name = parts[0]; 
  age = parts[1]; 
  nameVlaue.add(name); // This should be in the loop as you need to add every new value to the list
  ageValue.add(age); // This should be in the loop as you need to add every new value to the list
}
```

As a side note, always copy/paste the code as such from IDE. Do not type it here yourself, as you tend to make a lot of typos and syntax mistakes.

Comment: data=list.get(j).toString();Type mismatch: cannot convert from Person to String

Comment: You need to override `toString()` in your `Person` class to return data as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the String objects `name`, `age` with in the loop

Bacause these String objects are overloaded.

And also change the condition as `j < list.size()` inside for-loop

```
for ( j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) 
{                   

  data=list.toString(); 
  System.out.println("arraylist :::::"+data);
  parts = da.split(" ");
  name = parts[0]; 
  age = parts[1]; 
  nameVlaue.add(name);
  ageValue.add(age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This code its working fine:
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("rahul 25 ");
        list.add("karthik 24");
        list.add("arjun 30");

          ArrayList<String> nameValue = new ArrayList<String>();        
          ArrayList<String>  ageValue = new ArrayList<String>();        

          String name="",age="";

          int j=0;              
          String data=null; 
          String[] parts = null;





          data=list.toString(); 
          System.out.println("arraylist :::::"+data);
         /* parts = data.split(",");
          for(String str:parts){
             String namePart[]=str.split(" ");
             name=name+" "+namePart[0];
             age=age+" "+namePart[1];
          }*/
          for (String str:list) 
          {   
             String namePart[]=str.split(" ");
            name = name+" "+namePart[0]; 
            age = age+" "+namePart[1]; 
          }
         /* name = parts[0]; 
          age = parts[1]; 
        */

        nameValue.add(name);
       ageValue.add(age);

System.out.println("name::"+ nameValue);//                
System.out.println("age ::"+ ageValue);

    }
```

}

Comment: arraylist am getting from the server...based on arraylist i hva to loop list.size()

Comment: String data=list.toString(); 
 
   
   for (String str:list) 
      {   //change type of str to person

Comment: you can use it for your requirement. you just pass your list which is coming from DB instant of new list.